# Remote Development Workflow with Tomcat and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, tomcat

Currently, I have tomcat installed on the production server to serve my java webapps. I develop in eclipse at my personal workstation and then I use an ant script to build the project into a war file and deploy that on the server.

This setup works well when I am on the same network as the server because deploying is almost instantaneous. However, now that I am working remotely uploading the war file to the server is slow and in most cases very redundant (there are about .5 GB of static media included in the war file).

**Is there a better way to update my webapp on tomcat from eclipse and if so what are the best options for implementing such a solution with minimal effort?**

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/).  It transmits just the updates to the file, so it will greatly speed up your process.  Also depending on how complex your application is you might look into installing [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) on your personal workstation. It works well with eclipse and lets you check the new code almost instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you want is to have the exploded war file(your root app/result of ant compile) sit in your tomcat web-apps folder. Tomcat will deploy it based on the host or context tag in server.xml.

This way, you can just drop your $app/WEB-INF/classes into the application and, if context reload is enabled, the new files will be deployed immediately.